# How to force an event.on('blur') event to be called before ng-blur event?

Tags: angularjs

So this is mainly to guarantee backwards compatibility. I need to add additional functionality on blur to a large number of html elements without having to edit the controller methods called by the ng-blur attribute of those elements.

I wrote a directive to do this, but the problem is the directive method seems to always finish executing after the ng-blur methods in the controller. I need the directive method to finish executing before the ng-blur method in the controller begins.

Here is the basic format of the code:

```
<input test-directive ng-model="testValue" ng-blur="ngBlurTest(testValue)">
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('testDirectives', [])

.directive('testDirective', [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl, test) {
            element.bind('blur', function() {
                    console.log('This needs to appear first')
                }
            });
        }
    };  
}])
```

Controller (Method)

```
$scope.ngBlurTest = function(value) {
    console.log('TEST FROM CONTROLLER: ' + value);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but try setting priority of the directive to a really high number, for example:

```
.directive('testDirective', [ function() {
    return {
        priority: 1000000,
        restrict: 'A',
        ...
```

Also try using addEventListener, but don't forget to clear it:

```
var listener = function(event) {...};
element[0].addEventListener('blur', listener);
...
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    element[0].removeEventListener('blur', listener);
});
```

Also try setting useCapture parameter of addEventListener to true:

```
element[0].addEventListener('blur', listener, true);
```

Comment: I tried with priority 100 and 10000 before and I just tried with your number of 1000000, but it didn't seem to work :(

Comment: If that doesn't work, you'll have no other option than to change controller code to wrap blur handlers in $timeout

Comment: Thanks for the help. What i ended up doing was changing ng-blur to ng-blur-td in the html and then passing in the function and calling it in the directive instead of using the default ng-blur directive that angular provides. Not exactly conforming to the restrictions i put in the original question but close enough and got the job done just fine!